# Express.js PUT Request not updating MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm working on a project that is basically a super watered down social media website.

I have a chunk done already, but I'm having some issues creating a put request to my mongodb. Basically, I want to send a put request to update a numeric value to be able to have a like counter on each post.

What I'm trying do here is send a put request with a specific post id. I'm storing the post id in a hidden text box to reference it. This is pug formatted HTML:

```
input.form-control(type='hidden' value=item.id id='postId' placeholder='' name='postId' required='false')
      form(method='PUT' action='/update/{{post._id}}')
        button(type='submit') Like
```

Then in my router.js file I'm basically trying to take in that id and set the likes field in the Post schema to 1 (just for testing).

```
router.put('/update/:id', function (req, res, next) {
    let id = {
      _id: ObjectID(req.params.id)
    };

    Post.update({_id: id}, {$set:{'likes': 1}}, (err, result) => {
      if(err) {
        throw err;
      }
      res.send('user updated sucessfully');
    });
});
```

Here is my post schema

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  postText: {
    type: String,
    unique: false,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  },
  usernameText: {
    type: String,
    unique: false,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  },
  likes:{
    type: Number,
    unique: false,
    required: false
  }
});


var Post = mongoose.model("Posts", PostSchema);
module.exports = Post;
```

Any and all help would be highly appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the ObjectId. The ObjectId is generated by MongoDB and can't be changed by the user using query functions.

If you want to assign a unique id to each user for example, then create a separate field in your schema.

Answer (score 0):

1. You cannot change the ID
2. 'PUT' method is not supported directly as far as I know. You need method override